# Using an incrementing variable to access a variable in array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, counter

I'm trying to iterate through a collection of Markers and using a counter variable to wire up an event. `"When someone clicks a marker, show the infobox in position 'count'"`

The problem is as the script executes, the count variable is shared among each and every click event subscriber.

Meaning, a click in Marker A or B is wired to the same position, meaning the same InfoBox.

```
    var popups = [];
    var count = 0;

    @foreach (var marker in Model) {
        <text>
        /* Create Markers */
        popups[count] = {};

        popups[count]["marker"] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: themap
        });

        popups[count]["content"] = document.createElement("div");</div>';

        popups[count]["infoboxoptions"] = {
            boxClass: 'infobox-custom'
        };

        popups[count]["infobox"]= new InfoBox(popups[count]["infoboxoptions"]);            

        google.maps.event.addListener(popups[count]["marker"], "click", function (e) {
            popups[count]["infobox"].open(themap, this);
            /* PROBLEM IS HERE! ^ */
        });
        count++;
        </text>
    }
```

I understand the problem but don't know how to tackle it. Javascript is using the same variable for each click event and incrementing it after every iteration is also incrementing it for each click event.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. I used the Razor engine to ouput a hardcoded `number` value.

```
var popups = [];
var count = 0;

@{ var i = 0; }
@foreach (var marker in Model) {
    <text>
    /* Create Markers */
    popups[count] = {};

    popups[count]["marker"] = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: themap
    });

    popups[count]["content"] = document.createElement("div");</div>';

    popups[count]["infoboxoptions"] = {
        boxClass: 'infobox-custom'
    };

    popups[count]["infobox"]= new InfoBox(popups[count]["infoboxoptions"]);            

    google.maps.event.addListener(popups[count]["marker"], "click", function (e) {
        popups[@i]["infobox"].open(themap, this);
    });
    count++;
    </text>
    i++;
}
```